# Any ideas for creating custom deigned  virtual keyboard in C#?

Tags: c#, keyboard, virtual-keyboard

I'm creating virtual keyboard using C#, my friends designed it for me and sent it to me in .jpg format.

I have already created virtual keyboard that works nice but now I want to change the style of it and I want it to be like my friends designed it.

Any suggestions how to style keyboard?

I thought to use whole .jpg, analyse its areas and catch events from the areas user clicks but is there any other ways?

Keyboard style is designed so that buttons has not same width, height and in some cases not even shape.

so can anyone suggest where to start? and how to start?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Customized On-Screen Keyboards with the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708756.aspx) is a good start